# How To Open A Webpage in Full Screen Mode (IE) Automatically and The User Can Still Exit It By Pressing F11

Tags: internet-explorer, fullscreen

I've searched and googled a lot, but I just could not find a solution.

I want to open a webpage is full screen mode, but I need the following features:

1. If it only works for IE, it's fine;
2. It's a local file, say "index.html", when the user open it in IE, it is displayed in FullScreen mode automatically (without involving users pressing F11);
3. In full screen mode, the user is still able to press F11 to normal mode.

I have got a lot of Full Screen code, either JavaScript or "iexplore -k" kiosk mode, both of them lock the keys, preventing the user from pressing F11.

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made the below workaround, and it works

in help.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openmain()
{
    window.open('target.html', '_blank','toolbar=no,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600');
}
</script>
```

in the target.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.SendKeys("{F11}");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a security measure you cannot, not every user knows how to F11.

You can only do this if you make your website a html app ([HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). The closest thing you will be able to do cross-browser is create a screen-sized popup with minimal control interface.